# finding Value of an attribute using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote a code to scrape stock data by using each stock`s ID like the code below:

```
<a class="inst" href="loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=33854964748757477" target="33854964748757477">رنيك</a>
```

which the ID is "33854964748757477"
and since they will add new stocks and remove some i have to modify the code on a daily basis and since there are more than 150 stocks its time consuming, I'm searching for a way to scrape all the IDs using attribute "target" to find its value by selenium and then iterate through them.
the URL is: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F

Comment: You should look into `BeautifulSoup`. Probably some combination of `find_all()` with the attribute `target` might help you. Sadly your website doesn't work in my country so I can't help you further.

Comment: In html there is no `id` as such; there is an `i` which part of the attribute value of the `href` attribute. Is that actually always the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get ID attribute from rows located using `div[class='{c}']` css selector. `WebDriverWait` is used to wait for necessary condition of web elements. To get attribute `presence_of_all_elements_located` condition is enough.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# get all rows
rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='{c}']")))

# get ID attributes from rows
ids = [row.get_attribute("id") for row in rows]
```

Comment: it is perfect but im facing another issue. im getting this error `Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` i assume that since the webpage is updating i cant access the elements at some point so i have to find a way to kinda freez the webpage after loading.

Comment: You cannot freez, but you can get page source and parse it with beautifulsoup. Check BeautifulSoap and requests library, probably you not need Selenium at all.